# How to simulate a real checkout to test a new smudge filter?

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to force `smudge` filter to run by simulating a real life checkout.  Let's say I just created a new branch and did not modify any files but want to test my new smudge filter.  According to some answers such as [git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909620/git-smudge-clean-filter-between-branches) and [git: re-checkout files after creating smudge filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652242/git-re-checkout-files-after-creating-smudge-filter) it should be possible by running:

`git checkout HEAD --`

but in doesn't work with `git 2.9.0`. Method suggested in accepted answer here [How do I force git to checkout the master branch and remove carriage returns after I've normalized files using the "text" attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223527/how-do-i-force-git-to-checkout-the-master-branch-and-remove-carriage-returns-aft) works but I don't like because it seems fragile. Is there a safe way to do what I want to do in Git still today?

Comment: As VonC noted in the first edit to that answer ("edited Feb 9 '14 at 1:47"), you need to run not `git checkout HEAD --` but rather `git checkout HEAD -- <pathspec>`.  The <pathspec> to use can simply be `.` if you are in the top level of the work-tree.

Comment: @torek: I also tried it and it doesn't work with `git 2.9.0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check something out, first you will need to check something in. Just create a trash branch, add a test file with whatever is needed for the smudge test, commit it and test away. When complete delete the branch.